# Can I refer readers to link to a large figure?

Tags: graphics, formatting

I am preparing a journal paper and I have a very large figure in the SVG format that I would like to include in the paper. However, the figure is very hard to fit it inside the paper without affecting its resolution. I'm thinking to upload it to my website and refer the readers to it (by giving them its URL) because it will be very clear and they can also interact with it (e.g., zoom in and out). That way, I will be also able to shorten the length of the paper because right now it's longer the maximum number of pages.

Can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Does the journal allow online supplements?

Comment: I do not know I'll ask them

Comment: Do not use your own website for sharing figures. Use figshare.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the journals I help edit, we receive figures such as these. Some can be extremely massive, involving high-resolution images of photomicrographs or diagnostic tests. If the figures are a necessary part of the paper, then we would insist that they be submitted to us as is and we will work with the authors to find a suitable option for presenting the work if it passes peer review.

We have *never* allowed pictures or files to be hosted outside our ecosystem for two reasons. First, we have no control over those files so we will not know whether they have been modified in some way. Second, there may be issues with copyright.

I suggest that you flag this issue with the associate editor handling your manuscript for discussion following the peer-review process.

Good luck.